# Customized asyncContextManger not working concurrently on http requests

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio, aiohttp, contextmanager

I am using asyncio to send a bunch of requests to a web service concurrently. I cannot use aiohttp.ClientSession becuase the target service provides a client package with a lot of proprietary functions. Even if I can hack the authentication process to establish a session, I still have to implement those client's functions. I implemented my own Async Context Manager as in the following code snippet. It seems fine, except apparently the requests are executed sequentially. It takes 22 seconds where a concurrent run costs less than 3 seconds.

```
import aiohttp, asyncio, requests, time, json

start_time = time.time()

class MyRequests:
    def __init__(self, requests):
        self.requests = requests

    async def __aenter__(self) -> "MyRequests":
        return self

    async def __aexit__(
        self, exc_type, exc, tb
    ) -> None:
        pass

    def get(self, url) -> "MyResponse":
        return MyResponse(self.requests.get(url))

class MyResponse:
    def __init__(self, resp) -> None:
        self.response = resp
        self.url = self.response.url

    async def __aenter__(self) -> "MyResponse":
        return self
    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb) -> None:
        pass
        
async def get_pokemon(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        return resp.url

async def main():
    async with MyRequests(requests) as session:
        tasks = []
        for number in range(1, 50):
            url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_pokemon(session, url)))

        original_pokemon = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for pokemon in original_pokemon:
            print(pokemon)

asyncio.run(main())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Your tasks execute sequentially because there is no `await` expression anywhere in your program.  Asyncio programs perform a task switch only when they encounter an `await`.  Your context managers do nothing, because they perform neither setup nor cleanup - their only function is to increase the indent level of your code.  If you can't use aiohttp, perhaps you can study its implementation to see how it's constructed.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulCornelius . I added 'await' in several places to no avail. But following your hint I lookat aiohttp and requests module. It seems requests is synchronous, for there is a request-threads for async usage.

Comment: Just sprinkling await into your code does no good, unless you are actually waiting for some external resource at that point in the program flow.  If you don't re-implement aiohttp to meet you specific needs, perhaps request-threads will be a solution for you.

Comment: I used thread instead, which seems much more efficient. The run time of my test case with 50 concurrent airhttp connections is reduced from 2.5s to 0.6s with 50 threads.